# Selenium automation testing that helps manual testers to write tests scripts

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing this testing framework using selenium and Java so that manual testers are able to write test scripts and maintain them.I would want my testing framework to be in such a way so that manual testers basically write them as step by step procedures rather then understanding any of the underlying technology.

I want manual testers to write scripts as below:

```
    click("Configure");
    click("Network");
    click("Port Setup");
```

Configure, Network, PortSetup are all buttons with value/id: configure, network, port-setup. How do I write a framework with a method "click" that can scan through the entire page and click on buttons with values/ids that has been passed on click method by testers?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I'd suggest allowing the testers to utilize the element locators that Selenium provides ([See here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)). Doing otherwise and writing "all-purpose" wrapper methods such as the below will limit the flexibility that is needed when performing UI testing.

Provide a class with the following method. The class can be coded to have the driver method instance available to it, or you may want to pass the driver object in as a parameter.

```
public void click(String locatorValue)
{
     WebElement foundElement = driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue));
     foundElement.click();
}
```

Furthermore, this is just a base method. If you wish to handle additional situations or check for a By.name in case the id doesn't work, then implement the additional logic. Again, this can become a very narrow-focused mess very quickly. Good luck!